# magento readiness php error during module installation

Tags: magento2, installation

I am facing issue with Magento, module installation, same error showing like the beginning of Magento installation.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is check your Magento 2 requirements:
[CLick here to check](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-2.0-tech.html)

And install all latest version extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 requires the PHP 5.6 or above so update the php to 5.6 or above.

After that to add the extensions open php configuration file and remove comments from the extensions line  like

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Restart the server and check readiness again.